# VTD-XML Modifying huge files

Tags: xml, vtd-xml

As I know VTD-XML is able to process large /GB/ xml files.
You can use the classes:
- VTDGenHuge 
- VTDNavHuge 
- AutoPilotHuge

But unfortunately there is no XMLModifierHuge in the API. So the question is how can I modify /some elements in the xml tree would be inserted / large xml structure using vtd?

Thanks,

Ferenc

Comment: How big is your xml?

Comment: Size is around 1.6 gb

Comment: Your name sounds familiar, have we exchanged emails in the past?

Comment: I don't think so. I did not write you any emails. 
Please answer my original question It's more important.
In the meantime I googled out that 2GB of size can be accepted when namespace aware property is set to false when parsing a file.
Can I modify somehow xml files through vtd-xml which have more than 2 GB of size? Thanks.

Comment: Have you had any success parsing that 1.6gb file with vtd-xml standard version with ns turned off?

Answer (score 0):

I think the maximum file size supported in Java is 2GB for standard version of vtd-xml. However, that might only be possible with 64bit version of jvm. The other option available is to do it in C version of vtd-xml...